# Unit Testing and FOSUserBundle

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle

I'm writing unit tests for my Symfony 2 app which uses FOSUserBundle. Unlike this similar question:
[FOSUserBundle Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418855/fosuserbundle-unit-testing)

however, I don't use HTTP authentication (only a login form) and I need to use actual user entities not fake in-memory ones.

Despite a lot of searching and trying, I simply can't get it to work and the entire process is so intransparent that I don't even know where to begin. Here's the code I have:

```
protected $em;
protected $client;
protected $testuser;

public function setUp() { 
    $kernel = static::createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();
    $this->em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $this->em->beginTransaction();

    $this->client = static::createClient();

    $usermanager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $this->testuser = $usermanager->createUser();
    $this->testuser->setUsername('test');
    $this->testuser->setEmail('test@lemuria.org');
    $this->testuser->setPlainPassword('test');
    $usermanager->updateUser($this->testuser);
}


public function testLogin() {
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/en/login');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('_submit')->form(array(
        '_username'  => 'test',
        '_password'  => 'test',
        ));     
    $this->client->submit($form);

    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isRedirect(), 'should be redirected');
    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isRedirect('http://localhost/en/account'), 'should be redirected to account page');

    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();
```

and it fails on the 2nd assertion. As far as I can figure out, it redirects back to the login page.

I'm stuck and I don't even know where to start looking for a solution because it's apparently impossible to simply figure out WHY the login fails.

Comment: thanks, Michael. With some more debugging, I could it to log in. Now I'm wondering if I have to run through the entire login process for every single darn test, or if I can store the session once I tested that it works?

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding `echo $this->client->getResponse()->getContent()` to show you the actual response where you could look for errors

Comment: For your tests to maintain isolation, you will have to login for each one. You could add a method similar to `doLogin($username, $password)`

Answer (score 1):

Create an `AbstractControllerTest` and create an authorized client on `setUp()` as follow:

```
abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client = null;


    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = $this->createAuthorizedClient();
    }

    /**
     * @return Client
     */
    protected function createAuthorizedClient()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = $client->getContainer();

        $session = $container->get('session');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager */
        $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $loginManager \FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManager */
        $loginManager = $container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');
        $firewallName = $container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');

        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('username' => 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_TEST_USERNAME'));
        $loginManager->loginUser($firewallName, $user);

        // save the login token into the session and put it in a cookie
        $container->get('session')->set('_security_' . $firewallName,
            serialize($container->get('security.context')->getToken()));
        $container->get('session')->save();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

        return $client;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Please, replace the username with your test username.

Then, extends the `AbstractControllerTest` and use the global `$client` to make requests as follow:

```
class ControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest
{
    public function testIndexAction()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/');

        $this->assertEquals(
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );
    }
}
```

**This method tested and works fine**